# NHibernate subquery to check atribute of referenced object

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, nhibernate

I need to filter a page of my Concept model, Concept references TelecoCompany, so I want to filter by the name of that TelecoCompany. I was having some errors while comparing, so I realized I need to use some type of Subquery.

Here is what i have:

Concept:

```
public class Concept : BaseNhibernateModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Code.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Description.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the TelecoCompany.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual TelecoCompany TelecoCompany { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Family.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual FamilyService Family { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Type.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ConceptType Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether Enabled.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
```

Teleco:

```
public class TelecoCompany : BaseNhibernateModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the CompanyName.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Zones.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IList<Zone> Zones { get; set; } = new List<Zone>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether Enabled.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
```

Method

```
public Task<Page<Concept>> PaginatedAsync(FindRequestImpl<ConceptSearchFilter> filter)
{
    IQueryOver<Concept, Concept> qo = CurrentSession.QueryOver<Concept>(); ;
    if (filter.Filter != null)
    { 
        ConceptSearchFilter uFilter = filter.Filter;

        if (StringUtils.HasText(uFilter.Block))
        {
            qo.And(Restrictions.On<Concept>(x => x.Family.Block).IsInsensitiveLike(uFilter.Block, MatchMode.Anywhere));
        }

        if (StringUtils.HasText(uFilter.FamilyName))
        {
            qo.And(Restrictions.On<Concept>(x => x.Family.FamilyName).IsInsensitiveLike(uFilter.FamilyName, MatchMode.Anywhere));
        }

        if (StringUtils.HasText(uFilter.Description))
        {
            qo.And(Restrictions.On<Concept>(x => x.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(uFilter.Description, MatchMode.Anywhere));
        }

        if (StringUtils.HasText(uFilter.TelecoCompanyId))
        {
            //qo.And(Restrictions.On<Concept>(x => x.TelecoCompany.CompanyName).IsInsensitiveLike(uFilter.TelecoCompanyId, MatchMode.Anywhere));
            /*qo.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Concept>(x => x.TelecoCompany.Id).In(QueryOver.Of<TelecoCompany>().WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.CompanyName).IsInsensitiveLike(uFilter.TelecoCompanyId, MatchMode.Anywhere))));*/
        }
    }
    
    return PaginatedAsync(qo, filter.PageRequest);
}
```

I need to properly check the name of the object that Concept is referencing

Answer (score 0):

before adding filter on TelecoCompany it has to be joined. this can be done with

```
qo.JoinQueryOver(x => x.TelecoCompany).WhereRestrictionOn(t => t.CompanyName).IsInsensitiveLike(uFilter.TelecoCompanyId, MatchMode.Anywhere));
```